# Which PHP script does Super User use?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

Does anybody know which PHP script Super User is using? I plan to set-up a web site for college education issues. But I want it to have a script like superuser.com.

Where can I get this script?

Comment: It's just a modded version of phpBB really.

Answer (score 11):

It's not PHP, it's ASP.NET.

See here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, StackOverflow/ServerFault/SuperUser/... uses ASP.NET and the whole Microsoft Stack.

You might want to read the discussion about [SO clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones) one meta.stackoverflow.com (which is where your question belongs IMHO).

Comment: or even meta.stackoverflow.com ;)

Comment: no, meta is built with ASP Classic.

Comment: I thought meta was built with waffles and ponies

Answer (score 3):

Complex PHP websites are made of more than one script. A website *like* SU wouldn't be very difficult with PHP and a database, but SU was made with love :3

So, you want something like SU? Get learning PHP, it'll be great fun :)

Comment: O rly? http://blog.bitquabit.com/2009/07/01/one-which-i-call-out-hacker-news/

Comment: Note I was saying *like* with exactly that in mind. Something where you can post questions and then other users can post answers on them is something anybody with a few weeks of PHP knowledge could do. Building something as slick, visually impressive, integrated, and speedy as SO is certainly not.